# Electric sockets keep shorting

Tags: circuit-breaker, socket

I have an electric outlet to which I have connected an electric socket of 13amp and max wattage of 3250. I only connect an electric stove and a rice cooker to the socket but the fuse of this socket burns out every 2 months. The supermarkets don't sell a higher capacity electric socket than the one I have. I live in Dubai. What can I do to prevent the electric socket from burning out?

Comment: What do you mean "burned out"? Did the outlet physically burn up, or did it just stop working? Can you add a picture?

Comment: do not run the stove and the rice cooker at the same time

Comment: Also, what are the wattages of the oven and rice cooker?  What type of stove is it (those are typically hard-wired unless you're talking about a tabletop unit.

Comment: @machavity "fuse *of this socket* burned out" = "fuse burned out".  Prepositional phrase.

Comment: Doesn't make sense.  The electric socket may have a rating of 13 amp and 3250 watts.  However that is like the tires on your car having an HR rating (180 kph). That does not mean you can actually drive 180 kph. There are also other limiting factors.  What is the fuse rating?

Comment: You don't want a "higher capacity socket" unless you also upgrade the wire.  What kind of fuse or circuit breaker is protecting the wire, at the electrical panel?

Comment: In answer to all your questions: the fuse of the socket got burnt. I have a standard electric socket with 4 slots to plug in. I am not sure of the wattages of the appliances. I have purchased a new socket of the same specs as before, because I couldn't find one better with higher wattage.